# Integrating Wagtail with Django admin

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Are there any best practices or ideas for integrating the Wagtail admin with standard Django admin?

I am setting up a new Wagtail site but want to use some 3rd party apps. I know I can use the @hooks.register('register_admin_menu_item') hook to add menu items on the left hand side. I would like to keep a consistent look and feel for backend users so am not keen switching them between Wagtail admin and Django admin.

Is there any way to get the standard Django admin crud stuff to show inside Wagtail OR maybe fake integration by getting the Wagtail left menu to show in a customised version of Django admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wagtail 1.5 comes with `wagtail.contrib.modeladmin` module (ex [`wagtailmodeladmin`](https://github.com/rkhleics/wagtailmodeladmin)). I'm not sure that it will be helpful with 3rd party apps, but you may find it interesting for your own models.

Version 1.5 will be released soon. See [release notes](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/releases/1.5.html) and [documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/modeladmin.html).